# What is the risk of meningitis after nasal hair plucking?

Tags: infection, brain, hair, nose, inflammation

I heard board-certified dermatologist Dr. Sandra Lee (aka Dr. Pimple Popper) refer to a Nasolabial triangle as the "triangle of danger" on one of her tv show episodes. Re-reading the question and accepted answer to [How likely is intracranial thrombophlebitis after nasal hair removal?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20602/7951) the [Wikipedia source link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danger_triangle_of_the_face) in the question to the "triangle of danger", mentions risk for retrograde infection from the nasal area spreading to the brain causing meningitis or brain abscesses as well as the risk of cavernous sinus thrombosis (CST) mentioned in the accepted answer.

There are no citations linked to this claim in Wikipedia and I was wondering what the risk levels are for these 2 conditions. All I can find are newspaper reports repeating this [such as in Metro UK](https://metro.co.uk/2016/11/22/theres-a-danger-triangle-in-your-face-and-plucking-nose-hairs-can-kill-you-6275733/) with no risk level information other than "it is rare".

Is the risk level the same as CST — Approximately 0.2 to 1.6 per 100,000 per year (Plewa et al., n.d.) — or is the risk level different for meningitis or brain abcesses?

### References

Plewa MC, Tadi P, Gupta M. (n.d.) Cavernous Sinus Thrombosis. (Updated 2020). In: StatPearls [Internet] https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK448177/